# how to replace data url in variable

Tags: php, blogger

How do I replace a section of a url?
I have tried to use str_replace.

**Example:**

```
$urlTarget = 'https://www.example.net/';
$myDomain = 'https://www.mydmoain.net/';

$data = 'Some parents believe that baby walkers can help their baby's growth and development, especially helping the children to walk faster. However, is it true that baby walkers can help child development? Or even dangerous? Let's take a look at the pros and cons of baby walkers <a href="http://www.example.net/2018/01/news-doctor.html">below</a>';
$replace = str_replace($urlTarget,$myDomain,$data);
```

**Result:**

```
"Some parents believe that baby walkers can help their baby's growth and development, 
especially helping the children to walk faster. However, is it true that baby walkers can help 
child development? Or even dangerous? Let's take a look at the pros and cons of baby walkers 
<a href='https://www.mydmoain.net/2018/01/news-doctor.html'>below</a>"
```

I want to remove `2018/01/` and change the result to:

```
$data = 'Some parents believe that baby walkers can help their baby's growth and development, especially helping the children to walk faster. However, is it true that baby walkers can help child development? Or even dangerous? Let's take a look at the pros and cons of baby walkers <a href="http://www.mydmoain.net/search?q=new-doctor">below</a>';
```

**Note:-** I need to do this on URLs containing different dates.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I suggest you take a little time to take the [tour] and look at the [ask] page. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, and you are suppose to provide an attempt to solve the problem yourself first, then ask a specific question about it. Good luck!

Comment: Obligatory "what have you tried?"

Comment: if its a string, then why are u not using str_replace? and your url is completely changed not just `2018/01/`

Comment: @Kaddath thankyou sir, i am new member in here hehe :)

Comment: @devpro i tried to do it sir, i dont know how to get 2018/01 because the data is always randow , i dont know how to get 2018/01

Comment: @PatrickQ i have try use str_replace, but i have a problem,.

Comment: @FirhanAbiGael Show your attempt in your question and describe the result, including any errors.

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm confused, how do I change http://www.example.net/2018/01/news-doctor.html to http://www.mydmoain.net/search?q=news-doctor, using str_replace

Comment: ` example.net/2018/01/news-doctor.html ` its fixed>

Comment: @devpro what do u mean?

Comment: @FirhanAbiGael You said "i have try use str_replace"  Please _show_ this attempt in your question

Comment: i means if url is not fixed, you can just replace, if u have multiple url than its difficult

Comment: @PatrickQ done sir, u can see that

Comment: @devpro i have try to replace url, but another problem, i cant get the date (2018/01/) because they are random.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is going to make a number of assumptions, because you have been imprecise throughout your question.

I am going to assume that *both* original and desired URLs use "http" and not "https".  You go back and forth between the two in your question.

I am going to assume that the `href` attribute in the `<a>` tags is enclosed by double-quotes both in the original and the result.  Your question has doubles in the original and singles in the result.

I am going to assume that even though your question has "search?q=new-doctor" in the desired result, you actually want "search?q=news-doctor" when the input has "news-doctor.html"

I am going to assume that the date part of the original URL is always a 4-digit year followed by a slash followed by a 2-digit month.

Please, when asking future questions, pay attention to details, as they matter.  Especially in cases like this where the answer is going to utilize regular expressions.

The function we're going to use to get our desired result is [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$urlTarget = "http://www.example.net";
$myDomain = "http://www.mydmoain.net";

$data = "Some parents believe that baby walkers can help their baby's growth and development, especially helping the children to walk faster. However, is it true that baby walkers can help child development? Or even dangerous? Let's take a look at the pros and cons of baby walkers <a href=\"http://www.example.net/2018/01/news-doctor.html\">below</a>";

$resultUrl = preg_replace("@".$urlTarget."/\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*)\.(.*)\"\>@", $myDomain."/search?q=$1\">", $data);

echo $resultUrl;
```

Regular Expression Breakdown:

`@`: Starting delimiter. Not using the typical `/` so that we don't have to escape the slashes in the URL

`$urlTarget`: We only want to match URLs starting with "http://www.example.net"

`/\d{4}`: A slash followed by exactly 4 digits

`/\d{2}`: A slash followed by exactly 2 digits

`/(.*)`: A slash followed by any number of any characters (the characters are in a capturing group so we can reference them in the replacement)

`\.`: A dot (escaped) (used to split the file into name and extension)

`(.*)`: Any number of any characters (the extension, "html" in your example)

`\">`: A double-quote (escaped) followed by a greater-than `>` to catch the end of the `<a>` tag

`@`: Ending delimiter

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a46f013c01ece5e0d0ae3102c084c33307dfb97)

Comment: only `Regular Expression Breakdown:` will to future visitor. but good effort patrick